# Blender CTRL+R in restrict area

Tags: blender

Basically i want to do CTRL+R in between the edges that are in orange[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bl0r.png) but when i do CTRL+R it creates the edge to the whole plane[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIWJu.png) how can i make it so it only creates the edges in the area i want? I tried to change the vertices that are created in the new edges but it messes the whole plane and also I tried to delete them but as there are so many and it also deletes the faces it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [loop cut tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html) will cut through a quad and all quads connected to its target sides.

To stop the loop cut, you want the cuts to run into a non-quad face. In the example you show, you have an ngon at the end of of the face you want to cut, I would change that so that the two faces on either side of the target face are ngons.

See that the top example will cut through connected faces, while the lower one stops in the one face.

[image: example loop cuts]

Another option, that doesn't provide the multiple parallel cuts is the [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html), this allows you to cut between the points you specify and doesn't continue through any other areas. You can also use the knife tool to turn the sides next to your target into ngons so that the loop cut will stop there.

To remove the extra edges that you don't want, use [<kbd>X</kbd>->*Dissolve Edges*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html), or if that makes things collapse, use <kbd>X</kbd>->*Limited Dissolve*